# Equivalent of RxJS switchMap in ReactiveX/Rx.NET

Tags: rxjs, reactivex, rx.net

In **RxJS**, there is a [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) function. Is there an equivalent in **ReactiveX/Rx.NET**? I don't see one in the [transforming](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#transforming) documentation.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Edit**

`switch` is the equivalent.  http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html

In short, `switchMap` and `switch` will cancel any previous streams whereas `flatMap` will not.

Comment: flatMap and switchMap are definitely not equivalent

Comment: switchMap does cancel previous streams, flatMap doesnt

Answer (score 14):

There is no single SwitchMany in Rx.NET equivalent to switchMap in Rx.js. You need to use separate Select and Switch functions.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    .Select(_ => Observable.Return(10))
    .Switch()
```

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229197(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 2):

From http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html

> Switch operator subscribes to an Observable that emits
>   Observables. Each time it observes one of these emitted Observables,
>   the Observable returned by Switch unsubscribes from the
>   previously-emitted Observable begins emitting items from the latest
>   Observable.

As [MorleyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037170/morleydev) pointed, the .NET implementation is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229197(v=vs.103), so
the equivalent of RxJS switchMap in Rx.NET is a combination of Switch and Select operators:

```
// RxJS
observableOfObservables.pipe(
    switchMap(next => transform(next))
    ...
)

// RX.Net
observableOfObservables
    .Switch()
    .Select(next => transform(next))
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think you have the order correct. The `Switch` happens on inner observables but you haven't got any until you call `Select`. The above answer also has them the other way round.